# How to block / unblock signal handlers in pyGTK? Why handler_block() is not working?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm writing application which consist of a window with TextView and lot of dialog windows. TextView must connect to key-release-event signal and this collides with behavior of dialog windows.

The problem is that each time when user ends dialog window with enter key, dialog box disappears and TextView widget executes handler for key-release-event.

How to block key-release-event from executing, but only just after user closed dialog window with enter key?

This is small application witch demonstrates problem and is ready for testing possible solutions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk


class TestDialog(gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, 'test', parent, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL, (gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        self.get_action_area().set_sensitive(False)
        test_entry = gtk.Entry()
        test_entry.connect('activate', self.__on_entry_activate)
        self.vbox.pack_start(gtk.Label('Select entry and press Enter'), False, False)
        self.vbox.pack_start(test_entry, False, False)
        self.show_all()

    def __on_entry_activate(self, event):
        self.response(gtk.RESPONSE_OK)


class TestApp(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self, gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.set_size_request(640, 480)
        self.connect('destroy', lambda e: gtk.main_quit())
        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        test_button = gtk.Button('Press me')
        test_button.connect('clicked', self.__on_test_button)
        vbox.pack_start(test_button, False, False)
        self.__text_view = gtk.TextView()
        self.__id = self.__text_view.connect('key-release-event', self.__on_textview_key_release)
        vbox.pack_start(self.__text_view, True, True)
        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

    def __on_textview_key_release(self, widget, event):
        buff = self.__text_view.get_buffer()
        buff.set_text('You have failed! TextView has executed key-release-event :P')

    def __on_test_button(self, event):
        self.__text_view.handler_block(self.__id)
        dlg = TestDialog(self)
        if dlg.run() == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            self.__text_view.grab_focus()
        dlg.destroy()
        self.__text_view.handler_unblock(self.__id)

    def run(self):
        gtk.main()


app = TestApp()
app.run()
```

Comment: There are very few problems where using GtkTextView:key-release-event is the solution...  Trying to workaround perfectly valid signal emissions (the enter key is likely released in the text view after all) is probably not worthwhile: you should first look at GtkTextBuffer api and see if any of those signals do what you actually want.

Comment: @jku Ok. But why when I uncomment lines with handler_block() / handler_unblock(), signal handler is still executed?

Comment: That's probably because the dialog is destroyed (and signal unblocked) before the key is released

Comment: @jku gtk.Dialog objects can block / unblock signal handlers of other widgets? It cant be the case i moved self.__text_view.handler_unblock() before dialog.destroy(), nothing changed :/

Comment: Why don't you add some debug prints and see for yourself? As far as I can tell the `__on_test_button()` function can return _before_ the key is released: moving code around in that function will not make a difference.

Comment: @jku Achh, now I see it. Thanks! :D